# Date text field asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, html, visual-studio

Can anyone lead me in the right direction as to how to set a textbox such as this:

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxDate" runat="server" CssClass="fields"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Into a masked text box that meets this style **"mm/dd/yyyy"**

Comment: What do you mean by "set a textbox... into a masked textbox"?

Comment: To mask input on the client side textbox you'll need to use JavaScript and / or jQuery. Is that in scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just simply convert the `DateTime` object to that format in server-side code?

Try this

```
DateTime dateTime = "your-date-time";
var asString = dateTime.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

`asString` will now have the format you've converted the DateTime object to. It will be string. So, after this step you can execute this

```
txtBoxDate.Text = asString;
```

..this might be the code you're looking for.